# How do I iterate through the elements of a table and change the background color of each element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have looked at previous answers for how to iterate through a table and I cannot get it to work. I must be doing something stupid. Here is an example:

I have this in CSS

```
td{width: 30px; height: 30px;
} 

<body onload = "setBackground();"> 

<table id = "table1"> 
    <tr id = "row1">
       <td>Stack</td>
       <td>Overflow</td>
       <td>Is my life saver</td>
    </tr>
</table> 

</body>
```

Now, in JS I have this

```
function setBackground() {

var table = document.getElementById("table1"); 

//i found this in a previous stack overflow answer and tried it

for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) { 

   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) { 

  //this is for debugging purposes... I can't even get this to work
   alert(table.rows[i].cells[j]); 

   table.rows[i].cells[j].style.background = "orange"; //just an example

    }  
 }
}
```

Note that I call the function in my body tag, and this is not working. I have been trying to figure this out and I can't! Also, I don't know JQuery. If someone can kindly help me I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not create the table with javascript???  [jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/uLorOwO/2)

```
<div id="tableContainer" >
    </div>



     <script>
      function setTable() {

var tableCntr= document.getElementById('tableContainer') ;
 var tblHTML = "<table>" ;

var colors = [['red','blue','green'],['orange', 'black', 'purple']]  ;

  for(var i=0;i<colors.length;i++) {
   tblHTML +="<tr>";

    for(var j=0;j<colors[0][0].length;j++) {
      tblHTML += "<td style='background:" + colors[i][j] + "'> </td>" ;
    }
       tblHTML += "</tr>" ;
 }
tblHTML +="</table>" ;
console.log(tblHTML);
tableCntr.innerHTML = tblHTML ;  
}


window.onload = setTable;
    </script>
```

Comment: In my program, I did make the table with JS. I just did not want to post all of my code in the question since I was interested in only iterating through the cells. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: no problem.. if you found my code helpful.. could you please check it to green.. i will appreciate it :)

Comment: I will do that but I am not sure how to. It says requires reputation > 15 required to vote. Is there something else I can do?

Comment: since you have asked the question..you can mark the answer as accepted.. you can find how to do it in the about page... http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 2):

Without using jquery:

```
(function() {
    function setBackground() {
        var table = document.getElementById("table1"); 

        //i found this in a previous stack overflow answer and tried it
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) { 
            for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) { 
                //this is for debugging purposes... I can't even get this to work
                alert(table.rows[i].cells[j]); 

                table.rows[i].cells[j].style.background = "orange"; //just an example
            }  
        }
    } 
    setBackground();
})();
```

And you don't need `body onload`

Here, you will find: http://jsfiddle.net/h7ks4/

Answer (score 0):

why not to color it using css only like this

```
td {
    background-color:orange;
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cHtEZ/)

Comment: Because I am not setting it only to orange. I was using that as an example. I am making a paint program that you select a color and every time you scroll over a table element it changes the color. The code above was just for a little example.Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to use jQuery you can try this:

```
$('#table1 td').css('background', 'orange');
```

But if you want to perform some more complicated operations try `.each` function

```
$('#table1 td').each(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'orange');
    //or plain javascript if you prefer
    this.style.background = 'orange';
});
```

`.each` will iterate through all `td`s and `this` keyword inside the function will refer to currently looped `td`.